# Is it possible to have an html link that links to a different html page without clicking?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have some autogenerated html documentation for a python project. When autogenerating this the 'main page' is created as index.html inside /manual/_build/html/index.html. I want to have a manual.html in the root folder that links to the index.html. I can put the following in manual.html:

```
<a href="manual/_build/html/index.html">link</a>
```

which makes a clickable link to index.html. I would like to be send directly to index.html without having to click on anything. Is this possible?

Thanks,
Niek

Comment: Are you referring to a redirect?

Comment: Or do you mean that it should work on hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your HTML `<head>` tag:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=index.html">
```

Comment: That keeps refreshing the page

Comment: @NiekdeKlein Sorry my mistake, I misread as you wanting to redirect index to manual. My edit will redirect manual to index. No javascript required.

Answer (score 1):

Just redirect it to index.html..Write this in manual.html...

```
<script>
document.location = "manual/_build/html/index.html";
</script>
```