# Make an hyperlink to an other page without the HTML a-tag, but after an animation finished playing

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I would like to make a web banner and I want it to have a hyperlink to an other page.

Sounds like an easy task? Yes, but I can't use the HTML   tag because I don't want to go to an other page started by a click event.

I want to link to an other page after an animation finished playing.

I'm hoping for a JS solution (if it's possible).

so:

First: I want to drag and drop an html-element,

Second: I want to play an CSS/JS animation,

Third: I want to hyperlink to an other page, (this is the part were in need help).

I don't have any code an don't ask to write it for me, I just want to know how to make a hyperlink without clicking something.

I have found an similar question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140699/is-it-possible-to-have-an-html-link-that-links-to-a-different-html-page-without), but it doesn't cover what I'm looking for. I want to link after the user interacted.

Comment: When you say "link," do you mean "redirect?"

Comment: What you mean with "hyperlink" and "link", if it should not redirect to another page?

Comment: I mean I want to go to an other HTML

Comment: Do you mean you want to redirect automatically after the animation has finished? Or load new content to the same page without changing the location?

Comment: For the redirect, you can use window.location.href = 'http://newurl.com'; If you know exactly how long the CSS animation will take, you can simply use setTimeout() to wait that long and then redirect with the above code.

Comment: I want to redirect to an other page automatically, after the animation finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the `window.location.href="http://www.stackoverflow.com";`

Here is an example of how you would do it at the end of an animation using jQuery.

**JavaScript**

```
$("#startAnimation").on('click',function(){
  $("#bunny").slideDown(1000,function(){
    window.location.href="http://www.stackoverflow.com";
  });

});
```

**CSS**

```
#bunny {  
  display:none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <div id="bunny"><img src="http://i.guim.co.uk/static/w-620/h--/q-95/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2010/8/5/1281041145130/Farms-wildlife-schemes-bo-006.jpg"/></div>
<div>
    <button id="startAnimation" type="button">Start animation</button>
</div>
```

[See the JSBin](http://jsbin.com/qohirecane/3/)

Comment: It is strange how much a person can change after the timespan of 3 years. I barely recognize myself writing this question. Unnecessary information and badly explaining the question. I just started developing around that time, and was really stuck at that point unable to search with the right keywords to make the browser redirect the user without the user clicking an anchor tag. Good those days are over, when even simple tasks like this took me hours to fix, and me being unable to describe my problem.

Answer (score 0):

After the animation has finished playing, you can run a script that would redirect the user to another page:

window.location.href = 'your_page.html';